# How can I use a variable as the name of object's method?

Tags: php, oop, syntax

Here is my code:

```
$method_name = 'mymethod()';
$obj = new Myclass();
$obj->$method_name;
```

As you see I've used `$method_name` as the name of a method. But it throws this error message:

> Undefined property: app\classes\Myclass::$mymethod()

How can I fix it?

Comment: How is PHP supposed to know that you want to call a method, and not access a property called "mymethod()"?

Comment: @deceze It has two parenthesis in the end of it. So it's obvious it is a method.

Comment: Looking at this: `$obj->$method_name` it's not obvious at all. It would actually be quite maddening if PHP decided whether `$obj->$method_name` is a property access or a method call based on the string contents of the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid using string to do reflection... And use the [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) and the [ReflectionMethod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php).

However, the proper way of doing it is:

```
$method_name = 'mymethod';
$obj = new Myclass();
$obj->$method_name();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use callback function [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php). To do this You need to make an array:

- The 1st element is the object
- 2nd is the method

  `call_user_func(array($player, 'doIt'));`

You can also do it without `call_user_func`:

```
$player->{'SayHi'}();
```

Or:

```
$method = 'doIt';
$player->$method();
```

Answer (score 1):

You set method name to be `mymethod()`, that is invalid.

Set it just to `mymethod`:

```
$method_name = 'mymethod';
$obj = new Myclass();
$obj->{$method_name}();
```